# Laravel page running with no servers it looks like

Tags: apache-http-server, port, nginx

I have been having major issues, kind of like this:  [cannot create a project in Laravel](https://github.com/acquia/blt/issues/2383) , with Laravel after installing XAMPP (was able to kind of normally operate it at beginner-level with just a LAMP setup) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Now I finally have a new project running:

[image: running project and terminal screenshot]

In the left pane is the project running at `localhost:8000` that can be refreshed and it persists.  In the right pane is my terminal that apparently shows no apache servers running nor any nginx servers running.  And `lsof -i :8000` shows:

```
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420 ~ $ lsof -i :8000
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
php7.2  8955 nobu    6u  IPv4  91934      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
```

Does anyone know what is happening, ie. how can I have this page running with `php artisan serve` when it doesn't look like there is a server running locally unless `php7.2` is a server???

Comment: FWIW PHP can run as a server using the -S option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Dave, yes I just learned about this built in server and now trying to get Laravel working with XAMPP as shown here:  [xampp and laravel](https://www.5balloons.info/how-to-install-laravel-5-5-with-xampp-on-linux/)